# Powershell: dealing with Tomcat manager CSRF protection

Tags: powershell, tomcat, tomcat7, csrf

I am trying to load session tool throught Tomcat manager using Powershell. The thing is, it is protected by anti-CSRF plugin, so the link looks like this i.e.:

```
http://servername/manager/html/sessions?path=/application&org.apache.catalina.filters.CSRF_NONCE=4DA3A97B62C58761CC2F0B9FFB6F16C7
```

The thing is, when I try to download webpage source, I get error:

```
"The remote server returned an error: (403) Forbidden."
```

The code I am using to retrieve this information is:

```
$url_session_tool = "http://servername/manager"
$login_manager = "login"
$password_manager = "password"
$webclient = New-Object System.Net.WebClient
$credCache = New-Object System.Net.CredentialCache
$cred = New-Object System.Net.NetworkCredential($login_manager, $password_manager)
$credCache.Add($url_session_tool, "Basic", $cred)
$webclient.Credentials = $credCache
```

Then I search for specific url pattern to get link to session details for the specific application, when I get the url to $webpage, the following code gets executed:

```
#$webpage = http://servername/manager/html/sessions?path=/application&org.apache.catalina.filters.CSRF_NONCE=4DA3A97B62C58761CC2F0B9FFB6F16C7
$credCache.Add($webpage, "Basic", $cred)
$webclient.Credentials = $credCache
$stuff = $webclient.DownloadData($webpage)
```

My question is: How to deal with this CSRF protection using Powershell? Any ideas?

Comment: It seems that you need to use URL redirection feature.